# Не работает загрузка локализованных ресурсов с помощью Glide

Tags: java, android, kotlin, glide

Есть графические ресурсы которые лежать в папках:
`drawable-nodpi` и `drawable-zh-rCN-nodpi`.

И следующий код:

```
  Glide.with(this).load(resId)
            .apply(RequestOptions.fitCenterTransform()
                    .dontAnimate()
                    .dontTransform()
                    .priority(Priority.HIGH)
                    .override(com.bumptech.glide.request.target.Target.SIZE_ORIGINAL))
            .into(imageView)
```

и

```
imageView.imageResource = resId
```

Проблема в том что первый вариант, при включенной китайской локализации - все равно грузит картинку с `drawable-nodpi` ,а второй вариант правильно подгружает ресурс с папки  `drawable-zh-rCN-nodpi`

**Вопроc:** можно ли как то подгружать локализованные ресурсы с помощью `Glide` ?

Answer (score 2):

Вообщем все решилось чистой кеша `Glide`:

```
Thread {
    Glide.get(activity.applicationContext).clearDiskCache()
}.start()
Glide.get(activity.applicationContext).clearMemory()
```